# Unity XCode Build Error - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this linker error. I deleted the entire Firebase Unity Packages and re-imported. I deleted the Library folder in Unity and re-imported. 
Any ideas what to do?

```
Ld /Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/SBI.app/SBI normal arm64
    cd "/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
-arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk
-L/Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos
-L/Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher
-L/Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac
-L/Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/nanopb
-L/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS -L/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Libraries -L/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Libraries/Paroxe/PDFRenderer/Plugins/iOS
-L/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase -L/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS
-F/Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos
-F/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks -F/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -filelist /Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SBI.LinkFileList
-Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/SBI-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt
-miphoneos-version-min=10.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SBI_lto.o
-fembed-bitcode-marker -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lc++ -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -lz -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework SafariServices
-framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -framework MediaToolbox -liPhone-lib -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia
-weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lil2cpp /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI\ Unity\ App/iOS/Libraries/Paroxe/PDFRenderer/Plugins/iOS/pdfrenderer.a
-lFirebaseCppAuth -lApp -lFirebaseCppDatabase -lCameraShot -lFirebaseCppApp -lAuth -lFirebaseCppStorage -framework StoreKit -framework MobileCoreServices -weak_framework Metal -lPods-Unity-iPhone -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SBI_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/spin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-enkmoyzogomvvoceetdbfdeibmah/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/SBI.app/SBI

ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: ltmp0 from /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o) ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase7invites8internal17InvitesIosStartup7OpenUrlEP13UIApplicationP5NSURLP12NSDictionary in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(invites_ios_startup_c984389ff3a709f86a31469c46d90947.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(invites_ios_startup_46c19a18bc3bfd97c73a835bd6a5e1bf.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase7invites8internal17InvitesIosStartup7OpenUrlEP13UIApplicationP5NSURLP8NSStringP11objc_object in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(invites_ios_startup_c984389ff3a709f86a31469c46d90947.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(invites_ios_startup_46c19a18bc3bfd97c73a835bd6a5e1bf.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase7invites8internal17InvitesIosStartup15DidBecomeActiveEP13UIApplication in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(invites_ios_startup_c984389ff3a709f86a31469c46d90947.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(invites_ios_startup_46c19a18bc3bfd97c73a835bd6a5e1bf.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase7invites8internal17InvitesIosStartup20ContinueUserActivityEP13UIApplicationP14NSUserActivityU13block_pointerFvP7NSArrayE in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(invites_ios_startup_c984389ff3a709f86a31469c46d90947.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(invites_ios_startup_46c19a18bc3bfd97c73a835bd6a5e1bf.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase7invites8internal17InvitesIosStartup22s_invites_ios_startupsE in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(invites_ios_startup_c984389ff3a709f86a31469c46d90947.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(invites_ios_startup_46c19a18bc3bfd97c73a835bd6a5e1bf.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase4util30ClassMethodImplementationCacheC2Ev in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase4util30ClassMethodImplementationCache9GetMethodEP10objc_classP13objc_selector in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase4util30ClassMethodImplementationCache26GenerateRandomSelectorNameEP13objc_selector in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase4util30ClassMethodImplementationCache9SetMethodEP13objc_selectorP8NSString in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRSAMAppDelegate in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FIRSAMAppDelegate in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase4util30ClassMethodImplementationCache18ReplaceOrAddMethodEP10objc_classP13objc_selectorPFP11objc_objectS7_S5_zES3_b in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase4util30ClassMethodImplementationCache14GetCreateCacheEPPS1_ in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol
__ZN8firebase4util23ForEachAppDelegateClassEU13block_pointerFvP10objc_classE in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libApp.a(util_ios_9862d331d1cca065e43d69802976c2ac.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppApp.a(util_ios_66b49b9aa9d3b68615dad361aa0a3b7b.o) duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_PhoneListenerDataObjC.listener_mutex in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o) duplicate symbol __ZN8firebase4auth17PhoneAuthProviderD2Ev in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o) duplicate symbol __ZN8firebase4auth17PhoneAuthProviderD1Ev in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o) duplicate symbol __ZN8firebase4auth17PhoneAuthProviderC1Ev in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o) duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_PhoneListenerDataObjC.active_listener in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o) duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PhoneListenerDataObjC in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o) duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PhoneListenerDataObjC in:
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
    /Users/spin/Desktop/SBI Unity App/iOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase/libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o) ld: 71 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You have duplicate libraries in your project. You'll need to find them and exclude one (or more) of them by marking it as not for iOS in the inspector or just delete them..

Comment: Yes I found them and deleted. Now it compiles. Thank you for your help.